# How can I hide other actions for some users which are neither recipient nor sender?

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending embedded request using rest api. I can get recipient view url by setting authentication method as 'email'. In this view there are other actions like void, delete, view history, view certificate. But I want to hide this options for some user and show it for some user. Also I want to hide some actions and not all in some cases. Is there any way using api or some setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the "Other Actions" dropdown:

- View History: Account wide setting, either enabled or disabled. You will need to reach out to DocuSign support to enable/disable this option.
- View Certificate: Account wide setting, either enabled or disabled. You will need to reach out to DocuSign support to enable/disable this option.
- Void: This should only appear if the Sender=Recipient case.
- Decline: Option to decline can be controlled in the signing branding file.

Comment: Thanks Luis for helpful response, but there are more options like re-send, clone, correct, form-data, data-changed. How can hide these options?. Also  void option is available even if recipient is not sender.

Comment: Please include more details of the API calls you are making to re-create this behavior. At a minimum, the HTTP verbs and the URL endpoints you are calling.

Comment: I am using docusign apiexplorer to verify various views. I am passing my docusign account id and envelopeid to generate url. For createSender and createConsole views I get these options. For complete documents I get 're-send' option. Following is url of apiexlorer: https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeViews

Comment: Ok, that sounds like embedded SENDING as opposed to embedded SIGNING which was mentioned in the question. My response was applied to the signing section. As a sender, you have complete control of envelopes you generate - I cannot think of options to disable such options.